# Vim auto indent private keyword

Tags: c++, vim

I'm learning Vim (I'm using gVim)
I need to do the following:
Suppose I typed this:

```
class MyClass {
    private
}
```

After typing the `:` after private, result should be:

```
class MyClass {
private:
}
```

How can I do automate that behaviour?
I tried with

```
:imap private: <Home><Delete>
```

But I feel it's not an elegant solution at all.
I already installed c.vim by Fritz Mehner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
set cindent
set cinoptions=g-1
```

Reference: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html

Comment: Acctually, the number given is the indentation that you want (read the  help) so you can use `set cino+=g0`.

Comment: yeah, `g0` is what you want, not `g-1`.  I use `=` instead of `+=` because I want to specify my `cinoptions` explicitly.